# My python sqlite update statement doesn't commit

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update

I am trying to write some Python SQLite3 CRUD statements.
I think I have the update statement written correctly, but there's obviously a problem I can't see.
The statement executes, but the database does not update.
The Insert and Read statements work ok.
I have omitted the create database and db_insert() functions as they are working...

My Code:

```
    import sqlite3 as sql


    def db_read():
     try:
       conn = sql.connect(database_file)

       c = conn.cursor()

       with conn:
         c.execute("SELECT * FROM netdevices")
         result = c.fetchall()

         conn.commit()

       return result

      except:
       print("Database Read Error")
       print(traceback.format_exc())


    def db_update(record_id, ip_address, device_name, connection_type, username, password):
      try:
        conn = sql.connect(database_file)

        c = conn.cursor()

        with conn:
         sql_cmd = "UPDATE netdevices SET ip_address = @ip_address, device_name = @device_name, connection_type = @connection_type, username = @username, password = @password WHERE id=@record_id"
         sql_values = [record_id, ip_address, device_name, connection_type, username, password]
         c.execute(sql_cmd, sql_values)

         conn.commit()

         print('Database Update Successful')

      except:
       print("Database Update Error")
       print(traceback.format_exc())
      
      
      db_insert(1, '10.10.10.1', 'Gateway', 'ssh', 'cisco', 'cisco')
      db_insert(2, '10.10.10.2', 'WorkshopSwitch', 'telnet', 'cisco', 'cisco')
      print('READ: ' + str(db_read()))
      print('-------')
      db_update(2, '10.10.10.250', 'WorkshopSwitch', 'ssh', 'admin', 'P@ssw0rd1')            # Update not working???
      print('-------')
      print('READ: ' + str(db_read()))
```

It gives this output:

```
    Database Insert Successful
    Database Insert Successful
    READ: [(1, '10.10.10.1', 'Gateway', 'ssh', 'cisco', 'cisco'), (2, '10.10.10.2', 'WorkshopSwitch', 'telnet', 'cisco', 'cisco')]
    -------
    Database Update Successful
    -------
    READ: [(1, '10.10.10.1', 'Gateway', 'ssh', 'cisco', 'cisco'), (2, '10.10.10.2', 'WorkshopSwitch', 'telnet', 'cisco', 'cisco')]
```

As you can see the update is not made.
Maybe I'm missing some SQL errors by my very simple try: except: statement?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: Which library are you using? The `@variable` syntax is not part of the built-in Python sqlite3 library as far as I can tell from the docs

Comment: I am using sqlite3  "import sqlite3 as sql"  . I have used SQLite with C# so I thought this would work, maybe there's a better approach?  The Insert and Delete functions I've written with the same style have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally found the answer :)

The sql_values array needs to be in the same order as the @variables in the statement.

I had id=@record_id at the end of the UPDATE statement but listed first in the array.

Python is matching the variables in order like old-style string formatting, not looking for @variable and matching with the same variable in the array.

Error:

```
sql_cmd = "UPDATE netdevices SET ip_address = @ip_address, device_name = @device_name, connection_type = @connection_type, username = @username, password = @password WHERE id=@record_id"
sql_values = [record_id, ip_address, device_name, connection_type, username, password,]
```

Correct:

```
sql_cmd = "UPDATE netdevices SET ip_address = @ip_address, device_name = @device_name, connection_type = @connection_type, username = @username, password = @password WHERE id=@record_id"
sql_values = [ip_address, device_name, connection_type, username, password, record_id]
```